# Python sqlite added rows to SELECT result which not changed by UPDATE commit

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have `python3` code working with local `sqlite3` database that makes selection from a table and in `for` cycle updates data in same table. I noted that making `commit` within cycle increases number of rows processed by the cycle, some rows start to appear twice in debug `print` and additional rows are NOT ones updated as I see in debug printout by unique `id`. If `commit` is done after `for` cycle, all if OK. Is it normal for `sqlite` `select` to be so dynamicccc? and why, how select works in sqlite engine than? I may suspect it can omit some results too... Can I fix my `SELECT` output somehow without `fetchall` to temp variable?

Below the code:

```
myQuery = 'SELECT id, disk, filename, filepath, filesize, filetime FROM filesdata WHERE disk = ' + diskToFind + ' AND filepath LIKE  ' + folderToFind + deletionFilter

c_find = dbConnection.execute(myQuery)

for rowToFind in c_find:
    uprint (rowToFind['id'], rowToFind['filepath'], rowToFind['filesize'], rowToFind['filetime'], ' tofind') 
    # some long if-s etc. to update only rows conforming to some criteria  
    dbConnection.execute('UPDATE filesdata SET deletion = "todelete" WHERE id = ?',(str(rowToFind['id']), ))
    uprint ('updated: ', rowToFind['id'])
    dbConnection.commit()
```